# Ocultar div,(o lista), cuando variable retorna vacía

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy buscando ayuda con esto de las variables vacías, lo que tengo es una página que me trae las variables de datos cargados en MySQL, es una lista con detalles de un inmueble,( como si tiene cochera, piscina, etc.), y trato de que cuando no tiene uno de los posible items no me muestre ese "li", ya que me genera un espacio que afecta al diseño, 
Algo así tengo,

```
li $pileta li
li $cochera li
li $terraza li
Etc.
```

Necesito que si por ejemplo `$cochera` esta vacía no genere ese li.

Aclaro que me funciona si no le pongo `height` en css, pero como a la lista le quiero incorporar un "i fa fa " a su derecha, ahí esta el problema, ya que el icono lo defino fijo en la lista así;

```
Li i class fa fa...i.   aca con php la variable /li
```

Y cierro `li`

Comment: Hola Alberto Charly! Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tu pregunta no está muy clara. Puedes mostrarno tambien lo que has intentado? Recuerda leer [ask] para hacer preguntas de más calidad. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué framework estás usando para generar el HTML?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código correcto (sin quitar los `<` y `>`)?

Answer (score 4):

Para detectar si una variable está vacía puedes usar [`empty`](http://php.net/empty). Comprobará si la variable está definida y en caso de estarlo comprobará si es una cadena vacía u otro valor considerado como tal.

Tu código quedaría:

```
<?php
/* Si no está definido ninguna ni enviamos el <ul> */
if (!empty($pileta) || !empty($cochera) || !empty($terraza)) {
?><ul>
<?php
  /* Si está definido $pileta enviamos su <li> al navegador */
  if (!empty($pileta)) {
?>  <li><?= htmlspecialchars($pileta) ?></li>
<php
  }
  if (!empty($cochera)) {
?>  <li><?= htmlspecialchars($cochera) ?></li>
<php
  }
  if (!empty($terraza)) {
?>  <li><?= htmlspecialchars($terraza) ?></li>
<php
  }
?></ul>
<?php
}
```

Si te lías con tanta apertura y cierre de etiquetas también podrías usar:

```
<?php
/* Si no está definido ninguna ni enviamos el <ul> */
if (!empty($pileta) || !empty($cochera) || !empty($terraza)) {
  echo '<ul>', PHP_EOL;
  /* Si está definido $pileta enviamos su <li> al navegador */
  if (!empty($pileta)) {
    echo '<li>', htmlspecialchars($pileta), '</li>', PHP_EOL;
  }
  if (!empty($cochera)) {
    echo '<li>', htmlspecialchars($cochera), '</li>', PHP_EOL;
  }
  if (!empty($terraza)) {
    echo '<li>', htmlspecialchars($terraza), '</li>', PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo '</ul>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: El `ul` solo se mostrará si todas las variables están definidas; creo que deberías cambiar los `&&` por `||`.

Comment: Cierto, gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

Ya que va a ser un condicional bastante repetitivo, por qué no hacer una función, creo que sería la forma más limpia.

```
// creamos la función
function echo_li ($var)
{ 
    // si existe y no está vacía
    // y si no es un Array
    // o si es igual a cero
    if ( ( !empty($var) AND !is_array($var) ) OR 0 == $var )
    { 
        echo '<li>'. $var .'</li>';
    } 
} 


// Creamos la lista
echo '<ul>';
echo_li ($pileta);
echo_li ($cochera);
echo_li ($terraza);
echo '<ul>';
```

Según la documentación de `empty()`:

> Devuelve `FALSE` si la variable existe y tiene un valor no 
>   vacío, distinto de cero. De otro modo devuelve `TRUE`.
>   Con `empty()` las siguientes expresiones son consideradas
>   como vacías:

```
 Expresión  | Descripción
------------+--------------------------
    ""      | una cadena vacía
    0       | 0 como un integer
    0.0     | 0 como un float
    "0"     | 0 como un string
    NULL    | NULL
    FALSE   | FALSE
    array() | Un array vacío
    $var;   | Una variable declarada, pero sin un valor
```